# Adding form field dynamically

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am preparing a WordPress web site for a non-profit in that I need to clone 3 input fields according to the user requirement. If they want, they can click an add button to increase input fields. Something like in attachment.

I am using Contact Form 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the plugin [Smart Grid-Layout Design Extension for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/).  It allows you to build table field input just like what you are describing, including many other useful tools to build powerful form layouts that are pure-css responsive.